# How can I remove a item class from a child's item in css and react?

Tags: reactjs, menu, parent-child

I want to delete a class or its effect if the parent element has no thanks element, or be able to choose to refer to its reference so that it can be selected, but I can't find a solution on the Internet and some of my ideas have already been used and I need some suggestion in that situation do. The situation is as follows: I have a menu in which the submenu is nested and the whole is guided by a recursive function that calls itself going down levels if taxonomies in the menu have children. And now I want to remove the effect on items that don't have children, which means that the menu can be expanded with the arrow.

A recursive function that calls itself creating categories (parents) and subcategories (children).

```
function NavBarLink({ ...props }) {
  const [classOpener, setClassOpener] = useState(false);
  const pathToCategories = `/categories/${props.codename}`;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  function handleTaxonomies(codename) {
    dispatch(catchCodeNameTaxonomies(codename));
    setClassOpener(!classOpener);
    return codename;
  }

  return (
    <span
      className={(classOpener && "opener active") || (!classOpener && "opener")}
    >
      <Link
        to={ pathToCategories }
        onClick={() => handleTaxonomies(props.codename)}
      >
        {props.name}
      </Link>
    </span>
  );
}

function NavBarItem({ ...props }) {
  function generateLink() {
    return (
      <NavBarLink
        name={props.name}
        codename={props.codename}
      />
    );
  }
  function generateSubmenu() {
    return <Menu items={props.terms} />;
  }
  function generateContent() {
    const content = [generateLink()];
    if (props.terms) {
      content.push(generateSubmenu());
    }
    return content;
  }
  const content = generateContent();
  return (
    <li> {content}</li>
  );
}
export default function Menu({ ...props }) {
  function generateItem(item) {
    return (
      <NavBarItem
        name={item.name}
        terms={item.terms}
        codename={item.codename}
        onClick={props.handleId}
      />
    );
  }

  const items = props.items.map(generateItem);
  return <ul className="menu-ul-child">{items}</ul>;
}
```

[image]

EDIT::
My new solution with purpose:

```
function NavBarLink({ ...props }) {
  const [classOpener, setClassOpener] = useState(false);
//add two icons
  const arrow = <i class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i>;
  const arrowDown = <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>;

  function handleTaxonomies() {
    setClassOpener(!classOpener);
  }

  return (
       //your purpose
    <span
      className={`opener ${classOpener ? "active" : ""}`}
    >
      <Link
        className="d-flex justify-content-between"
        to={pathToCategories}
        onClick={() => handleTaxonomies(props.codename)}
      >
        <span>
          {props.name}
        </span>
      //add two icons depending on the state
        <span>
          {props.showArrow ? (classOpener ? arrow : arrowDown) : ""}
        </span>
      </Link>
    </span>
  );
}

function NavBarItem({ ...props }) {
  function generateLink() {
    return (
      <NavBarLink
        name={props.name}
        codename={props.codename}
      //your purpose
        showArrow={props.terms && props.terms.length > 0}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to provide a new property like `showArrow`to `NavbarLink`. From your code snippets I think the `showArrow` can be set by `item.terms`. So you can do something like this:

in NavbarItem

```
  function generateLink() {
    return (
      <NavBarLink
        name={props.name}
        codename={props.codename}
        showArrow={props.terms && props.terms.length>0}
      />
    );
  }
```

Then extract the CSS part for drawing the arrow to a special class and check for `showArrow` in NavBarLink:

```
   <span
      className={`opener ${classOpener ? "active" : ""} ${props.showArrow ? "arrow" : ""}`}
    >
....
```

I've changed the `className` concatination to string literals. For me this is much more readable and it's easier to do all permutations.

Comment: I little change for you purpose :-) but is very useful for me because I see another solution. Thank you very much! If you want see my resolve then read a edit above.